# build error after adding Commoncrypto file for swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, commoncrypto

I added "NSData+CommonCrypto.h" and "NSData+CommonCrypto.m"' for use sha256.
I also add bridging header "chekit-Bridging-Header.h" and I wrote
`#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>` in the file.

In the building setting, I checked the file is added in Swift compiler - code generation objective-c bridging header.

10 errors occurs when build like above picture:
[Click here to see my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSJcq.png)

Thanks!

Comment: i write #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

Answer (score 0):

The import part sounds OK, however, it seems that the code you added is not using ARC (While your project does). You will need to go over the added code and convert it to ARC.

See more details of how to do this:

- https://maniacdev.com/2012/01/easily-get-non-arc-enabled-open-source-libraries-working-in-arc-enabled-projects